# ping pong in socket io version 4.4.1 not work Automatically

Tags: soc

the server send ping to client only once and the client responds but after that the server doesn't ping again causing timeout and disconnection

the server option is
{
path: "/socket/events",
transports: ["websocket],
allowUpgrades: false,
pingInterval: 10000,
pingTimeout: 25000
}

the client option is
`{ auth: {token: accessToken}, transports: ['websocket'], path: "/socket/events", upgrade: false, autoConnect:true }`

Answer (score 0):

Do not set `allowUpgrades: false` in your server options. By doing this you are disabling the connection to upgrade from polling to websocket. Also in your server and client options keep `transports: ["polling","websocket"]` to allow fallback to polling in case of websocket failure.